# Materialize CSS Tabs and Flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I am working with http://materializecss.com/ and Flask to build a dashboard and one of the features I am using is their Tab feature.  Unfortunatly I cant seem to master setting a tab active after I make a post request to my server.

This is what I currently have for my Flask code and my 2 templates:

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("tabs.html")

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def results():
    return render_template('results.html', data=data['reports'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Layout.html:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3" id="n"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" id="s"><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" id="t"><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="news" class="col s12">
      {% block news %}{% endblock%}
    </div>
    <div id="search" class="col s12">
      {% block search %}{% endblock%}
    </div>
    <div id="twitter" class="col s12">
      {% block twitter %}{% endblock%}
    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

tabs.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} 
{% block news %}
<h1>News</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block search %}
<form id="search" class="col s12" action="{{ url_for('results') }}" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="Address" type="text" class="validate" name="Address">
      <label for="Address">Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
      {% block results %}{% endblock%}
{% endblock%}
{% block twitter %}
<h1>TWITTER</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Now what I have occurring is when I click to search under the search tab I am sent back to having the News tab active.  When I click the search tab my results block is there and accurate but I am trying to find a way that it doesnt set the active tab back to default.

I have looked at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/
and using

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% set active_page = "index" %}
```

but that doesnt seem to work as the jquery that is used by materializeCss either conflicts with it or trumps it.

I have also looked at using the materializeCSS Jquery manual setting of an active tab by using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
  });
```

which I have set in both layout.html and tabs.html and I cant seem to get this to work either.

All thoughts and help are appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work in your case, but I am using materialize with Atom Electron and had trouble changing tabs via buttons/icons and couldn't get the "select_tab" method to work either. I ended up adding my own function for changing tabs via "onclick" methods using the following jquery:

```
function selectTab( id ) {
  $(document).find('a[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
}
```